# How to read ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y))?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In a question I asked here: [p(x)⇒∀x.p(x) is contingent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417547/px%E2%87%92%E2%88%80x-px-is-contingent/38417592#38417592)
It seems that there's tendency to agree upon  p(x)⇒∀x.p(x) is the same as ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y)), whereas ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y)) is read as if p(x) is true for **some** x, then it is true for all x.

However I don't understand where's the quantifier **SOME** came from, since there no quantifier '∃' in '∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y))'

Is there any sort of quantifier distribution law makes the quantifier changed in the ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y)) ?

Answer (score 2):

> there's tendency to agree upon p(x)⇒∀x.p(x) is the same as ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y))

No, it isn't the same (the truth of the first depends on `x`, the truth of the second doesn't); the second is the *universal closure* of the first. The linked textbook does consider them the same, but it's far from universal. I believe the more common definition is [the one in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(logic)), by which the first is not a sentence.

> Is there any sort of quantifier distribution law makes the quantifier changed in the ∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y)) ?

Yes; if `q` doesn't depend on `x`, you can see this chain of equivalences:

```
∀x.(p(x)⇒q) ≡
∀x.(¬p(x)∨q) ≡
(∀x.¬p(x))∨q ≡
¬(∃x.p(x))∨q ≡
(∃x.p(x))⇒q
```

Comment: Why does ∀x.(p(x)⇒q)  **not** equivalent to (∀x.p(x))⇒q ?

Comment: Just consider the case where `q` is false. Then `∀x.(p(x)⇒q)` is `∀x.¬p(x)` and `(∀x.p(x))⇒q` is `¬∀x.p(x)`. Hopefully you already know, or can understand, why those aren't equivalent. I've edited the answer to explain why the law I gave holds.